# подскажите как лучше написать jquery плагин

Tags: jquery

Пишу небольшой плагин на jquery, с помощью которого добавляются миниатюры к слайдеру и при клике по ним осуществляется переход на нужный слайд, также при свайпе по слайду, миниатюра активного слайда становится активной , написал, когда слайдер один - все работает, если добавить второй слайдер, все ломается, подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка, и верное ли решение делать подобный плагин с помощью .find()? Чтобы проверить работоспособность без одного слайдера достаточно его закоментировать в html коде. 
в песочнице слайдер глючит бывает вот сам сайт http://webflow-slider-with-miniature.webflow.io

```js
(function($) {
   jQuery.fn.HeroSlider = function() {
     var HeroParent = $(this);
     HeroParent.find($('.hero-preview-wrapper')).find($('.hero-preview')).click(function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       HeroParent.find($('.hero-preview-wrapper')).find($('.hero-preview')).removeClass('active');
       $(this).addClass('active');
       var index = $(this).index();
       HeroParent.find($('.hero-nav')).find($('.w-round div:eq(' + index + ')')).trigger('tap');
     });
     HeroParent.find($('.hero-slider')).on('swipe', function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
         HeroParent.find($('.hero-preview-wrapper')).find($('.hero-preview')).removeClass('active');
         var ActiveSlideIndex = HeroParent.find($('.w-round')).find($('.w-active')).index();
         HeroParent.find($('.hero-preview-wrapper a:eq(' + ActiveSlideIndex + ')')).addClass('active');
       }, 100);
     });
   };
 })(jQuery);
 $('.hero-slider-wrapper').HeroSlider(); //инициализация первого
 $('.hero-slider-wrapper-2').HeroSlider (); //инициализация второго
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/css/webflow-slider-with-miniature.webflow.0ce7634a0.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://daks2k3a4ib2z.cloudfront.net/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/js/webflow.49df81509.js"></script>

<!--Первый слпайдер начало-->

<div class="hero-slider-wrapper">
  <div class="hero-slider w-slider" data-animation="slide" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1">
    <div class="w-slider-mask">
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img class="image" sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
      <div class="w-icon-slider-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
      <div class="w-icon-slider-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-nav w-round w-slider-nav">
      <div class="w-slider-dot w-active" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
      <div class="w-slider-dot" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
      <div class="w-slider-dot" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-preview-wrapper">
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block" href="#">
      <div>1</div>
    </a>
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block active" href="#">
      <div>2</div>
    </a>
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block" href="#">
      <div>3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Первый слайдер конец-->
<!--Второй слайдер начало -->
<div class="hero-slider-wrapper-2">
  <div class="hero-slider w-slider" data-animation="slide" data-duration="500" data-infinite="1">
    <div class="w-slider-mask">
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74a96577342964014add1_pIzF19vePJQ-2.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b1c577342964014adf0_q9YDFoetE_I.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
      <div class="hero-slide w-slide" style="transform: translateX(0px); opacity: 1;">
        <img class="image" sizes="100vw" src="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI.jpg" srcset="http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-500x334.jpeg 500w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-800x534.jpeg 800w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI-p-1080x720.jpeg 1080w, http://uploads.webflow.com/57f748fc37d7eda1401efd00/57f74b2937d7eda1401f0502_TIQ5UnoTUXI.jpg 1280w">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slider-arrow-left">
      <div class="w-icon-slider-left"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="w-slider-arrow-right">
      <div class="w-icon-slider-right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="hero-nav w-round w-slider-nav">
      <div class="w-slider-dot w-active" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
      <div class="w-slider-dot" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
      <div class="w-slider-dot" data-wf-ignore=""></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hero-preview-wrapper">
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block" href="#">
      <div>1</div>
    </a>
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block active" href="#">
      <div>2</div>
    </a>
    <a class="hero-preview w-inline-block" href="#">
      <div>3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--Второй слайдер конец -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы неправильно подошли к созданию плагина, вам нужно использовать один из популярных паттернов, которые учитывают то обстоятельство, что плагин может быть запущен более одного раза для нескольких элементов.

[jQuery-plugins patterns](http://shichuan.github.io/javascript-patterns/#jquery-plugin-patterns)

Вот самый простой:

```
;(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        pluginname: function(options) {
            this.defaults = {};
            var settings = $.extend({}, this.defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Могли бы вы объяснить, куда тут вставить тело плагина?

Comment: http://webflow-slider-with-miniature.webflow.io в первом рабоает все, во втором ничего, в третьем частично, тело вставил после var $this = $(this);

Comment: Используйте этот: https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/jquery-plugin-patterns/lightweight.html

Там все гораздо понятней + сразу видно как должен быть организован код.